# Hit song with misheard chorus

Tags: history

Here's a music trivia puzzle for you all:

What big international hit song had a chorus that was a garbled, misheard rendition of a much older hit song. The original song was in English, the newer song was in a mixture of languages.

I do have an answer in mind, but I'll accept a different answer if it turns out to have been a bigger hit than the one I'm thinking of.

Comment: What are the languages of the newer song ?

Comment: Spanish, English, Portuguese --although there were apparently different versions released in different countries.

Answer (score 2):

This question immediately brings to mind [The Ketchup Song (Aserejé)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Ketchup_Song_(Aserej%C3%A9)) by Las Ketchup.  Its chorus is a rendering, in Spanish-language nonsense syllables, of the English-language chorus of [Rapper's Delight](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rapper%27s_Delight) by the Sugarhill Gang.

Comment: This is indeed the song I was thinking of! Fun fact --within the song's narrative, the reason the chorus is garbled is because the person singing it is drunk, high, and doesn't speak English. :) I'll leave this open for a couple more days in the case anyone else comes up with an even better answer. I'd be curious if anyone else has ever had this concept. "Piano Man" has a similar narrative, but I don't think the song quoted in that one is a "real" one.

Comment: @ChrisSunamisupportsMonica I am sure that there is some other similar instance somwehere.  There's a whole category of language mistake named after a version of this phenomenon in which one phrase is misheard for another, [mondegreens](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mondegreen), but I have some vague recollection of some other nonsense phrase that is actually supposed to mean something.  Maybe I'm thinking of [Mairzy Doats](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mairzy_Doats).

Comment: @phoog Maybe In-A-Gadda-Da-Vida?